# Running cron every 10 minutes

Tags: cron

I have a python script on my desktop: `/home/ceasor/Desktop/script.py`

In `/etc/crontab`, I wrote:

```
0 */2   * * *   ceasor    sudo python  /home/ceasor/Desktop/script.py
```

The python script is not getting run.  How do I run cron every 10 minutes?

Comment: Why do you call `sudo python`? If you want to run it as root, just specify that user in your `crontab`. Also `0 */2` means every 2 hours, not every 10 minutes.

Comment: It's on your Desktop? Then you have the wrong path in your crontab

Comment: can your account run sudo w/o a password?  IS python in the path that cron sees?. also that crontab says ever 2 hours.  if you want every 10 minutes use */10 * * * *

Answer (score 33):

Your line means runs at 0 minutes every two hours (ie 00:00, 02:00, 04:00, etc).

If you want to run something every 10 minutes :

```
*/10 * * * *  ceasor    sudo python  /home/ceasor/Desktop/script.py
```

I took the liberty to correct the wrong path.

FYI, these are the meaning of the values :

```
         field          allowed values
          -----          --------------
          minute         0-59
          hour           0-23
          day of month   1-31
          month          1-12 (or names, see below)
          day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
          username       any user from the system
          command        the command you want to run
```

And if you want to run something as root, you should put `root` instead of `ceasor` for the username and drop the `sudo`.

Answer (score 13):

Run a command every 10 minutes:

```
*/10 * * * *   ceasor    sudo python  /home/ceasor/script.py
```

The `*/10` token will fire the cronjob every 10th minute.

You could also enumerate every minute that you want it to fire off:

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * sudo python /home/ceasor/Desktop/script.py
```

Answer (score 4):

To run something every ten minutes, I normally put something like the following in my crontab:

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * sudo python /home/ceasor/Desktop/script.py
```

Adjust the 0,10,20,... as you need to hit the minutes of the hour you want.

Comment: you can use */10 instead of the enumeration, it means every 10 minutes

Comment: @Krtek:  Yes, that's been stated in other answers.  Both ways works, and I thought it would be good to make the OP aware of alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

For every ten minutes you need

```
  */10 * * * *     ceasor         sudo python /home/ceasor/Desktop/script.py
```

and if the script is in `Desktop/` you need to use that path as in my example here.